# Generalized lambda capture by value always located at the same address

Tags: c++

```
transform(begin(a_), end(a_), back_inserter(all),
  [vertices_ = vertices] (v3d<int> v) {
    // modify vertices_
  }
);
```

`vertices_` is captured by value. I hope to modify it and insert 
 it into `all` using the `back_inserter`. But when I `cout` `vertices_`'s address, I find that all `vertices_` have the same address, which means the former modification still exists, so I have to do:

```
transform(begin(a_), end(a_), back_inserter(all),
  [&vertices] (v3d<int> v) {
    v2d<int> vertices_ = vertices;
    // ...
  }
);
```

I don't think it is reasonable.

#### Q1: Is there any standard word?

#### Q2: Why do clang and gcc have such behavior? Is it a bug?

environment: clang and gcc

Comment: "I found all vertices_ is the same address, which means the former modification still exists. " - your assumption is incorrect

Comment: the captures are determined upon construction, not on each invocation

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "the former modification still exists"?

Comment: @SU3 transform will call lambda multiple times, so I think each `vertives_` is different. However, the truth is all `vertives_` is the same object in memory(their address is the same), so the modifications on the former `vertives_` still occurs to the latter `vertives_`.

Comment: Just because two objects have the same location in memory doesn't mean they're the same object. (Though in this case they are)

Comment: Lambda's get invoked by passing captured parameters to the function.

So the value of vertices_ is captured at the point when the lambda function is defined since you captured it by value.

In your sencond example you captured it by reference, so even if the capture point is the same the captured object is not a copy of it when it was created and shows you the current value.

More on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda 

Please check the lambda capture section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one instance of the lambda is passed to `transform()`, so there is only 1 captured value. `transform()` passes each item to the  `v` parameter of the same lambda object. That is why the address of `vertices_` is the same for each item when `vertices` is captured.  The code is *roughly* doing the following:

```
/*
transform(begin(a_), end(a_), back_inserter(all),
    [vertices_ = vertices] (v3d<int> v) {
        // modify vertices_
    }
);
*/

struct lambda {
    v2d<int> vertices_;
    v2d<int> operator()(v3d<int> v) {
        // modify vertices_
    }
};

auto first1 = begin(a_);
auto last1 = end(a_):
auto d_first = back_inserter(all);
lambda unary_op{vertices}; // <-- capture done here
while (first1 != last1) {
    *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++); // <-- lambda invoked here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `transform` will call lambda multiple times, so I think each `vertives_` is different.

You're passing the functor object to `std::transform`. For every iteration inside `std::transform` the operation will be performed on the same passed functor; it won't create a new functor for every iteration.

Here's one possible implemtation of [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform#Possible_implementation):

> ```
> template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, 
>          class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation>
> OutputIt transform(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, 
>                    OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation binary_op)
> {
>     while (first1 != last1) {
>         *d_first++ = binary_op(*first1++, *first2++);
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

As you can see it's always calling on the same functor `binary_op` for every iteration. There's only one lambda, then only one captured `vertices_`. So you're always modifying the same `vertices_`.

For the 2nd code sample, you're creating a local copy for every invocation of the lambda and these local copies are irrelevant.